# minimal number of vertices of a graph that can be split into two trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose a graph has no 3 cycle, and can be split into two trees, that is
the edges can be partitioned into two sets, each part form a tree.
For example:
[image]
(red and green indicate  partition)

I want to show that such graphs have at least $k-1$ vertices, where $k$ is the number of edges. Could anyone give a hint, or potentially a counter example? The only intuition I have for this problem is that the graph probably look like something in the image.

Comment: If you add one more red to green line to the one on he right you get a counter example. you are adding two edges and only one vertex resulting in 8 edges and 6 vertices. It also has no 3-cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $K_{n,2}$ which has no $3$-cycle, since it's bipartite.  The edges can be partitioned to form two copies of $K_{n,1}$.  It has $n+2$ vertices and $2n$ edges.

Comment: Do you think this is the lower bound? namely given $k=2n$ edges, the minimal amount of vertices is $n+2$?

Comment: I'm new to this site. I know you have answered the question, but if I want to discuss further variations of this question, should I do it here in the comment?

Comment: As I understand the rules, it's okay to ask for more information about the solution in a comment, but for a variation you should ask a new question.  So asking my opinion is okay, but if you really want to see a solution, you should ask a new question, so that people can find it; search won't find it in comments, as I understand it.    My guess is "yes", by the way.

Answer (score 1):

counter example

[image]

This graph has 6 vertices and 8 edges and contains no 3-cycles. It can be split in two trees in the same way that the original with 5 vertices and 6 edges can.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  Same counterexample I posted, with $n=4.$